# Solace integration with Websphere Application Server 8.5.5

Tags: solace, solace-mq

Can Solace integrate with IBM Websphere Application Server 8.5.5.0? We are thinking to eliminate the existing IBM MQ7.0 from our IBM WAS 8.5.5.0 integration components.

I have found one article/document on the Solace portal for IBM WAS 7/8.0, but not for 8.5.5.0? But we need to know the capability of Solace and whether it will integrate with IBM WAS 8.5.5.0 or not?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solace can absolutely integrate with IBM Websphere Application Server 8.5.5.0. The current Websphere Integration Guide that is available on the Solace dev portal is applicable to Websphere Application Servers 7.x and 8.x. It is available here: http://dev.solace.com/integration-guides/websphere-application-server/

The Solace JMS Resource Adapter is designed to be generic. It is generally able to integrate with any Jave EE Application Server.

If you have a support contract with Solace and you encounter any specific issues integrating Solace with any version of the IBM Websphere Application Server, you can contact support by emailing support@solace.com with a description of your issue.